# Output text if the SQL value is empty

Tags: php, sql, html-table

I'm trying to output the text 'N/A' into my table if there is an empty value stored for it in my SQL table. Here is what I have so far:

```
while($rowObj = $queryResult->fetch_object())
                {
                $eventTitle = $rowObj->eventTitle;
                $catDesc = $rowObj->catDesc;
                $catID = $rowObj->catID;
                $eventDescription = $rowObj->eventDescription;
                $venueName = $rowObj->venueName;
                $venueID = $rowObj->venueID;
                $eventStartDate = $rowObj->eventStartDate;
                $eventEndDate = $rowObj->eventEndDate;
                $eventPrice = $rowObj->eventPrice;                  

                echo "
                <tr>
                    <td> $eventTitle </td>
                    <td> " . (empty($catID)) ? 'N/A' : '$catDesc'. "</td>
                    <td> " . (empty($eventDescription)) ? 'N/A' : '$eventDescription'. "</td>
                    <td> " . (empty($venueID)) ? 'N/A' : '$venueName'. "</td>
                    <td> $eventStartDate </td> 
                    <td> $eventEndDate </td>
                    <td> $eventPrice </td>
                </tr>
                    ";
                }
```

Comment: if(strlen($catDesc) > 0){echo $catDesc;} else{echo "N/A";} http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php Or when you insert those values into your database you can give the ones with no value a value of "N/A".

Comment: you have error ?  .. wrong result?   .. what's the problem?

Comment: @MariusBegby thanks for help, how would I use this whilst also putting it into the table though?

Comment: @scaisEdge it currently just has an output which looks like this:
''N/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/A'

Comment: try use isset($catID)  ? 'N/A' : '$catDesc' instead of empty ( ..)

Comment: @scaisEdge unfortunately it still hasn't changed.

Comment: Nevermind, it's inside an echo statement so don't use if. Before the echo statement you can do `if(strlen($catDesc) < 1){$catDesc = "N/A";}`

Comment: @MariusBegby Thank you! It works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(empty($value)){
    echo "This value is empty";
}
```

Or
if you want to insert a value "into the table" if a field is empty

```
if(empty($value)){
 $value = "N/A";
 //INSERT QUERY
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

$value = empty($value) ? "NA" : $value;